# Notation $C(\overline{U})$ for function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

I am reading Partial Differential Equations by Lawrence C. Evans ([http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xushijie/pdf/textbooks/pde-evans.pdf](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Exushijie/pdf/textbooks/pde-evans.pdf)), and in appendix A on Function spaces pg 702 (711 of the above pdf) it says:

> $C(U) = \{u : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid u \text { is continuous}$}. 
> $C(\overline{U}) = \{u \in C(U) \mid u \text { is uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of }U$}.

My question is, is this "just notation", or is there some connection to the closure of U? That is to say, is the second definition a formal/equivalent way of saying "continuous functions on the closure of U?"

If it is "just notation", it seems somewhat poor; shouldn't the $C$ be "modified" and not the $U$? (as in $C^k(U)$ being k-differentiable functions or $C_c(U)$ functions w compact support).

If it is not "just notation", what's the connection between uniform continuity on bounded subsets and continuity on the closure?

Comment: $$C(\bar U)=\left\{u\in C(U)\mid \forall v\in \partial U, \lim_{\underset{w\in U}{w\to v}}u(w)\text{ exist}\right\}$$ which is equivelnt to your definition

Comment: I completely agree that this notation is *poor* (to say the least) because $U$ is by no means determined by its closure $\overline U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function is uniformly continuous in $U$, it can be extended to a continuous function on $\bar U$. See Surb's comment. Not only the limit exists on the boundary but by setting $u(v)=\lim_{x\in U, x\to v} u(x)$ for $v$ on the boundary you obtain a continuous function on the closure.

You can easily prove that using sequences and Heine's characterization of continuity (sequences approaching $v$ have images which are Cauchy sequences).